# Terminal cannot find Bash

Tags: bash

I am a beginner coder, so bear with me. I was doing the lynda.com tutorials on Ruby on Rails and in the Terminal typed in `nano .bash_profile` and then `export PATH="usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`. Now everytime I log in I get the message :

```
 -bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin': not a valid identifier
```

and I even when I tried to find it using `which $SHELL` it says that No such file or directory. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`PATH="usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`

should be

`PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Yeah, sorry that is actually in there but didn't write it in the question. I still have the same problem

Comment: @Przemek Copy/paste the **exact** line you used, especially including any whitespace like `export PATH = "something"` (the spaces matter). If you made that typo you could've easily made others.

Comment: I was supposed to type: export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH" . I believe I typed it in correctly when I did it but there is not way of checking now since I restarted my terminal. Is there a way that I can undo that and just start over?

Comment: If your Terminal works, just do `nano .bash_profile` again. If it doesn't, you'll need to open it in a text editor. Because it's a hidden file, use the instructions at http://www.howtogeek.com/211496/how-to-hide-files-and-view-hidden-files-on-mac-os-x/ under "View Hidden Files and Folders in the Open/Dialog".

Comment: I think the problem was that the terminal itself was screwed up. I typed in export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin into the terminal and now it is working. Thanks!